# Check if datagridview has no selected rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to start a `Sub` by checking whether a datagridview row has been selected.

it's possible for there to be no rows at all. I have tried:

`If isdbnull(lstInvoicesAndPayments.SelectedRows(0).Cells("DetailID"))= True Then`

but obviously if there is NO row, there is also no cell and I get an error.

Comment: `If lstInvoicesAndPayments.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then` evaluates to true if there's at least one row selected.

Comment: Thanks Vince!  this seems to work for now!

Comment: how do I give you a thumbs up?

Comment: I'm not sure you can with your low reputation. But a thank you is fine for me. :)

Comment: consider yourself thanked!

Comment: I found another solution which seems to be more logical : 'If IsNothing(lstinvoicesAndPayments.CurrentRow) Then' .... -- but thank you nonetheless!